# How to put LaTeX formulas in Word 2010?

Tags: latex, typing, mathematica, equation-editor, pdflatex

I have a problem to convert directly equations from Mathematica *(copied as LaTex) in Word 2010. Is there any option?

Comment: Why not copy from Mathematica into Word using MathML? Related question in [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/72806/954)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to modify the equations from within Word you can compile the equation with LaTeX and then include it as an image in your Word document.

You can also use services like http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php to directly convert to a pdf/jpg/gif/svg image an equation: simply paste the code copied from Mathmetica into the box and then click the link "Click here to Download Image".

Comment: I mean I must edit copied Latex equation, maybe to change the font in word or leveling. I heard for program tex2word, but almost nothing about information on internet.

Comment: @derdack: Have you seen this: http://word2tex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MathType](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/) for this. Just copy a *formatted* equation (you can convert a Cell into formatted `StandardForm` display by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) from within *Mathematica*'s FrontEnd and paste it in MathType.

Also, there is [LaTeX-to-Word](http://www.grindeq.com/index.php?p=latex2word) utility which allows to convert LaTeX documents into Microsoft Word format. Another alternative is [TeX2Word](http://word2tex.com/) utility suggested by [Werner](https://superuser.com/users/100579/werner).

Answer (score 0):

Even you don't need any add-ins. MS office gives almost a similar way of typing equation. What's more that you can use GUI along with a keyboard shortcut (Math Autocorrect option) in Ms Office. Using both (Gui and latex scripts) side by side provides greater flexibility. There is nice video about the same on [youtube link.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbTE-xLDPxtBP-TE2fS1MysSqFCkHh1N3) It covers most of the basics that you need.

Answer (score 0):

just copy the whole formula that you wrote in LATEX, then paste it in the word. 
Select the formula and in the MathType toolbox click oh "Toggle Tex". You will have the formula in word.